# How to tell the differences between the a and b in jaxb?

Tags: jaxb

For the following schema, Say both a and b are String type. JAXB generates a variable called aOrB. I know I can use instanceof if a and b are differnet types. But they are both String type now, how do I tell the differences? Someone mentioned to use something like Qname, JAXBElement . I have no idea how to do that. Can someone pls shine some light? thanks

```
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="a" minOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element ref="b" minOccurs="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it, its (JAXBElement) object).getName().getLocalPart() . sorry for the false alarm